# How to return only body contents in GuzzleHttp?

Tags: php, http, curl, guzzle

The returning JSON data comes with header contents that i don't need, is there a way of filtering the returned data?

Here is my PHP Code:

```
public function AreaGet($info){
    $res = $this->guzzClient->request('GET','v2/Address/Areas/Search',[
        'headers'=>['Authorization'=>'Bearer '.$this->keys()->access_token],
        'query'=>['countryCode'=>'ZAF','searchFor'=>$info->searchCity]
    ]);

    return json_decode($res->getBody()->getContents());
}
```

And this is the response I'm getting:
[JSON RESPONSE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2n8L.png)

Comment: Thank you for such a quick response, Unfortunately that documentation is outed, some functions have been removed.

Comment: Sir, i don't think you get my question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone contributed !

I have figured out the problem, i was supposed to set the 'debug' to false in my Authorisation script

```
$request = $this->guzzClient->request('POST', 'Login', ['debug' => false,'form_params'=> $data]);
```

Otherwise the response will come with http and server information appended into the body

Comment: Debug is false by default, unless you set it to true when you instantiate the client.